# Question related to arithmetico-geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

The question is $$\text{Find the sum of }0.2+0.004+0.00006+0.0000008+\cdots$$
My solution:
Given series can be written in the form $$S=\frac{2}{10}+\frac{4}{10^3}+\frac{6}{10^5}+\frac{8}{10^7}+\cdots(1)$$ Multiplying both sides by $10^{-2}$, we get
$$\frac{S}{10^2}=\frac{2}{10^3}+\frac{4}{10^5}+\frac{6}{10^7}+\cdots(2)$$
Subtracting equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$, we get $$S-\frac{S}{100}=\frac{2}{10}+\frac{2}{10^3}+\frac{2}{10^5}+\frac{2}{10^7}+\cdots$$
$$\implies\frac{99}{100}S=\frac{\frac{2}{10}}{1-\frac{1}{100}}=\frac{2}{10}\times\frac{100}{99}=\frac{20}{99}$$ $$\implies S=\frac{20}{99}\times\frac{100}{99}=\frac{2000}{9801}$$ But the answer given in the book is $\dfrac{2180}{9801}$. I checked my solution multiple times but can't figure out my mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 to your query, for nice work shown.  I verified your work.  Then, I used an alternate method and got the same result.  I think the answer in the book is wrong, and that you are right.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your work. In fact, plugging $\frac{2000}{9801}$ into a calculator gives $0.2040608101\dots$, which matches the original sum.

Comment: The book used a direct formula for the sum of arithmetico-geometric series and got $\frac{2180}{9801}$ as the answer.

Comment: @Myst1cal What direct formula of what series?

Comment: @user2661923 For an infinite A.G.P whose first term is $a$, common difference $d$ and common ratio $r$ where $|r|<1$ the sum is given by $$\frac{a}{1-r}+\frac{dr}{(1-r)^2}$$ This formula was used by the book but I never use this formula to calculate the sum.

Comment: @user2661923 I would be glad if you could share your alternate method to calculate the sum in the answer.

Comment: @Myst1cal See my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 What do you think about the formula mentioned in the book? Is it correct?

Comment: @Myst1cal Out of curiosity, I verified the accuracy of your formula, which simplifies to $$\frac{1}{1-r}\left[a +  \frac{dr}{1-r}\right].$$  In the present problem, with $~~a = d = \frac{2}{10},~~$ $r = \frac{1}{100},~~$ and $~~\frac{1}{1-r} = \frac{100}{99},~~$ this computes to $$\frac{100}{99} \times \frac{2}{10} \times \left\{1 + \left[\frac{1}{100}\left(\frac{100}{99}\right)\right]\right\}.$$

Comment: @Myst1cal See also the Addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate method, per request:

Let $\displaystyle S = \frac{2}{10}
\left[1 + \frac{1}{10^2} + \frac{1}{10^4} + \cdots\right] = 
\frac{2}{10}\times \frac{100}{99}.$

Then the desired sum is

$$ T = S\left[1 + \frac{1}{10^2} + \frac{1}{10^4} + \cdots\right]
= S \times \left(\frac{100}{99}\right) = \frac{2}{10} \times 
\left(\frac{100}{99}\right)^2.$$

**Addendum**
Actually, the underlying problem: how to evaluate 
$$ 
g(x) = \left(1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + \cdots \right) 
~:~ |x| < 1 \tag1$$
has 3 methods of attack.  The OP and I (in effect) used closely related but distinct methods, each of intermediate difficulty.

The (3rd) easier method is to use Calculus.

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \left(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots\right) = \frac{1}{1-x}.$

Then $~f'(x),~$ which equals $~~g(x),~$ as shown in equation (1) above, may be equivalently expressed as

$$\frac{(-1)}{(1-x)^2} \times (-1).$$

Comment: Really nice approach!

Comment: The calculus attack makes the problem elegant.